# FCM messages not getting delivered

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

I have setup a FCM client on my Android app. When I am trying to push the notification from Firebase console, the console says that message is delivered.

[This is the log screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1Eua.jpg)

But I am not able to see any notification delivered on my device.
I am getting following log on Android Logcat:

```
03-26 14:22:26.607 20227-31218/co.pushmessages V/FA: Connecting to remote service
03-26 14:22:26.617 20227-31218/co.pushmessages D/FA: Logging event (FE): _nf, Bundle[{_o=fcm, _sc=MainActivity, _si=3365666155092549436, _ndt=0, _nmn=msg, _nmt=1490518346, _nmid=8754479537222765642}]
03-26 14:22:26.637 20227-31218/co.pushmessages V/FA: Using measurement service
03-26 14:22:26.637 20227-31218/co.pushmessages V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
03-26 14:22:26.637 20227-31218/co.pushmessages D/FA: Connected to remote service
03-26 14:22:26.637 20227-31218/co.pushmessages V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 2
03-26 14:22:29.277 20227-20233/co.pushmessages D/dalvikvm: Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
03-26 14:22:31.667 20227-31218/co.pushmessages V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```

Is there a way to get the messages deliverd on the deice?

I have placed correct google-services.json in app folder and all signatures are correct.

My **app level build.gradle** is

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "co.pushmessages"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

My **project level build.gradle** is:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

My **Manifest file** is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="co.pushmessages">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIdService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"></service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Versions**:

Android Studio Ver 2.2.3

Android OS (device) Ver 4.4.4

**EDIT**

**MyFirebaseInstanceIdService.java**

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIdService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
    }
}
```

**MyFirebaseMessagingService.java**

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    public MyFirebaseMessagingService() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        // TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.
        // If the application is in the foreground handle both data and notification messages here.
        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
        Log.e(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        Log.e(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Did some changes in the Manifest file as suggested by mercury and now it works smoothly. Following is the final manifest file that made it work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="co.pushmessages">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".TargetActivity"></activity>

        <service android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIdService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to FireBase (android) example,
First i don't see the following action in your Manifest:

```
<service
    android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Second, I don't know /you havn't posted your `onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)`- is it being called?

Please go through the FCM guide:

[Set Up a Firebase Cloud Messaging Client App on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client)

[Send a Notification to an Android Device](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/android/console-device)

Comment: I have gone exactly through the instructions given by Firebase instructions given in the Android Studio Firebase plugin. OnMessageReceived is being called inside MyFirebaseMessagingService.

Comment: As I wrote, what about adding the action I mention above in your manifest? Have you done that ?

Comment: Anyway if your code reaches the OnMessagingService, meaning that you got the notification, you just fail to post it. You need to post your OnMessagingService code

Comment: I have added the service files in the main question. BTW, I started receiving messages after I made the change in Manifest that you suggested. Surprisingly, the Firebase instructions in Android Studio Plugin didn't ask me to declare the service the way you suggested me  :D
Thank you, you saved lot of time..!